# Is there any way to print widget property in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am a newbie in flutter my doubt is suppose I have a list of card in flutter and I want to print card's backgroundColor property value is there any way to do so??

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging

Comment: I want to show output in terminal..